# Aleatorizar List<File>

Tags: java

Tengo una lista de rutas en un fichero. La variable se llama `List<File> destination_list`.

¿Cómo podría aleatorizar esas rutas y que salga una cualquiera? ¿podría usar la clase [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, me imagino que con **¿cómo podría aleatorizar esas rutas y que salga una cualquiera?** te refieres a cómo obtener un elemento al azar, ¿verdad?.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Crea un ArrayList a partir del tu lista conteniendo los valores 
//de las rutas
List<String> shuffleList = new ArrayList<String>(tuLista);
//Permuta aleatoriamente la lista.
Collections.shuffle(shuffleList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro que podrías hacer uso de la clase [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Un ejemplo de uso para elegir un elemento al azar podría ser el siguiente:

```
List<File> destination_list = ...;
Random aleatorio = new Random();
/* Obtenemos un elemento al azar */
File archivoAleatorio = destination_list.get(
    aleatorio.nextInt(destination_list.size())
);
/* Mostramos cualquier propiedad del elemento File elegido */
System.out.println(archivoAleatorio.getPath());
```

Usamos `aleatorio.nextInt(destination_list.size())` para generar un número aleatorio entre `0` y el número de elementos de `destination_list` menos uno. Posteriormente usamos ese número en `destination_list.get()` para obtener ese elemento de `destination_list`.

Comment: Muchas gracias no sabía como podia imprementarlo , tambien tengo otra duda tengo este codigo

Comment: Hola @Hugo. Si es una duda de este código házmelo saber. En caso de que sea una nueva duda deberás crear una nueva pregunta [pulsando aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta pulsando en el icono del correcto (**✔**) que hay a la izquierda de mi respuesta.